# If multiple list items together in string

Tags: python, list

I have a dictionary with countries and their alpha2 codes.

```
all_countries = {
    ...
    "Cambodia": "KH",
    "Saint Kitts and Nevis": "KN",
    "Comoros": "KM",
    "Sao Tome and Principe": "ST",
    "Slovakia": "SK",
    "Korea, Republic of": "KR",
    "Slovenia": "SI",
    "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of": "KP",
    "Kuwait": "KW",
    "Senegal": "SN",
    ....
}
```

I need to replace in the following list the name of the country to alpha2 code

```
....
["Pusan National University Hospital", "49241 Busan", "Korea", "Republic of"]
["Severance Hospital", "03722 Seoul", "Korea", "Republic of"]
["Ospedale degli Infermi", "47923 Rimini", "Italy"]
....
```

Output should be:

```
....
["Pusan National University Hospital", "49241 Busan", "KR"]
["Severance Hospital", "03722 Seoul", "KR"]
["Ospedale degli Infermi", "47923 Rimini", "IT"]
....
```

And I have a script to change it

```
def get_alpha_code(row):
    for i in row:
        if i in all_countries.keys():
            country_code = all_countries[i]
            row.remove(i)
            return country_code
        elif i in all_countries.values():
            code = i
            row.remove(i)
            return code
    return None
```

But how I can check, that multiple items together are in the dictionary keys?
**For Example Korea**

Comment: in your list `"Korea", "Republic of"` is two different elementts but in dictionary it is single key

Comment: Yes. So I need to check? that these two different elements could be the whole name of the country

Comment: how to identify those two elements?

Comment: You dont need to change your dict, but make you data to the format that follows you dict.

Answer (score 0):

Is this work? I dont have whole data you have, but I guess the idea is to combine string to make it the format of your dict.

```
all_countries = {
    "Cambodia": "KH",
    "Saint Kitts and Nevis": "KN",
    "Comoros": "KM",
    "Sao Tome and Principe": "ST",
    "Slovakia": "SK",
    "Korea, Republic of": "KR",
    "Slovenia": "SI",
    "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of": "KP",
    "Kuwait": "KW",
    "Senegal": "SN",
    "Italy": "IT",
}


a = [["Pusan National University Hospital", "49241 Busan", "Korea", "Republic of"],
     ["Severance Hospital", "03722 Seoul", "Korea", "Republic of"],
     ["Ospedale degli Infermi", "47923 Rimini", "Italy"]]

def process_data(a):
    ll = []
    for row in a:
        if len(row) == 3:
            c = row[-1]
        elif len(row) == 4:
            c = row[-2]+', '+row[-1]
        rr = row[0:2]+[all_countries[c]]
        ll.append(rr)
    return ll

process_data(a)
```